# Using 1 button to access multiple database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to create an application using .net in c#. The problem I am facing is that I have a `comboBox` linked with 5 databases. I want to show the contents of each database separately in `dataGrid`. Whenever I select any column the contents must be shown in multi-TextBoxes(i.e the whole infomation say name, year etc ) so that I can `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` the data in connected environment. Can I use only these 3 buttons to modify the data of each database? Basically, I do not want multiple buttons for each database to modify the databases.

Comment: Platform/Technology not specified.

Comment: I am sorry sir, but I am using c#, .net and sqlserver 2000

Comment: So you are writing an ASP.NET application, right?

Comment: no sir its windows application, in visual studio 2008.using c#.database is created using sql server 2000.

Comment: So you are writing a WPF application, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass additional arguments to event handler and modify appropriate database

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Create five connection objects:

```
DataBase conn1;
DataBase  conn2;
DataBase  conn3;
DataBase  conn4;
DataBase  conn5;
```

And in `buttonClickEventHandler` (delete for example):

```
if(comboBox.SelectedIndex == 1) 
{
   DeleteItems(conn1);
}
```

Create a `DeleteItems` method:

```
public void DeleLeteItems(DataBase db)
{
   //delete items from db here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the info from the combobox which tells you the database used and then you can have something like

```
object selectedItem;
private void ComboboxSelectionChanged(...)
{
     selectedItem = combobox.SelectedItem;
}
private void ButtonClickEventHanlder(...)
{
    if(selectedItem == firstdatabase)
      //do this
    else if (selectedItem == seconddatabase)
      //do something else in the other db
    ...
}
```